# Autostart with AutostartCondition

Tags: autostart, gsettings

I want to run a program at a certain condition.

So I have created a `.desktop` file and put it in `/etc/xdg/autostart`.

the contents of the desktop file are:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=System Tray
Exec=/opt/testApp
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
NoDisplay=true
AutostartCondition=GSettings com.test testVal
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
```

And I have made a custom key with `gsettings` for a condition and compiled the schemas.

I confirmed whether the schema works, and it does.

```
gsettings set com.test testVal true
gsettings get com.test testVal
```

I typed the command above, and got "true".

However the Application I registered as Autostart doesn't run.

My questions are:

1. Do I have to restart or logoff for a test?
2. Is there a way to test autostart without reboot or logoff?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655066/autostart-with-autostartcondition and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176542/autostart-with-autostartcondition

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so, could you please write it as an answer to your own question?

Comment: @FernandoSilveira, I just posted an answer for it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can I answer 5 years later?

I was looking for a way to achieve the same and stumbled upon your question.
Here is how I did it:

1. Open Startup Applications
2. Select the App you want to conditionally open and click on edit
3. Add your condition to the command field

In my case, I wanted some apps to only automatically start on weekdays, so my command field went from this:

```bsh
/usr/bin/teams %U
```

to this:

```bsh
if [[ $(date +%u) -lt 6 ]]; then /usr/bin/teams %U; fi
```